# Case inside switch looping non-stop, even though i had break

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement

I just started learning c++, i am making this menu driven program using the switch case.
The problem is, when i enter one of the option it loops infinitely although i already used break.

```
    while (choice != 3)
    {
            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    int TIME;
                    cout << "Input time: " << endl;
                    cin >> TIME;

                    string ACTIVITY;
                    cout << "Input activity: " << endl;
                    cin >> ACTIVITY;

                    todo.addNode(TIME, ACTIVITY);
                    break;
                }

                case 2:
                {
                    int DELETE;
                    cout << "Which activity that you want to delete: " << endl;
                    cin >> DELETE;

                    todo.removeIndex(DELETE);
                    break;
                }

                default:
                {
                    cout << "Invalid input";
                    break;
                }
            }
}
```

For example, if i pressed 1, the program asks for the time and activity endlessly without breaking. When i pressed any numbers other than 1,2, or 3, it prints the invalid input endlessly.

Am i missing something?

Comment: The `break` inside a `switch` statement breaks out of that, not the enclosing `while` loop. To break out of the loop. then, you either need a flag or, if you prefer, you can `return` out of the entire function.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently your code breaks out of the switch statement, but cannot come out of the while loop as condition is not taken as input inside it.

To come out of the while loop, you need a flag to break outer while loop:

```
int flag=0;
while (choice != 3)
{
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            int TIME;
            cout << "Input time: " << endl;
            cin >> TIME;

            string ACTIVITY;
            cout << "Input activity: " << endl;
            cin >> ACTIVITY;

            todo.addNode(TIME, ACTIVITY);
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            int DELETE;
            cout << "Which activity that you want to delete: " << endl;
            cin >> DELETE;

            todo.removeIndex(DELETE);
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            cout << "Invalid input";
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

this is one implementation. your `flag=1;` statement might be else-where.

**Note1:** Dont use `return` in place of `break`, if there is something else to be processed in the function after this `while` loop. Otherwise, you can return from the if(flag == 1) condition.

**Note2:** Another option is to get choice input from the user in the default case. like so `cin >> choice;` the problem is your while loop does not take choice after it enters the loop because of this choice does not change and hence loops endlessly.

Comment: Thank you it worked, but i made a nearly same program before without using flag, but it breaks from the loop without looping endlessly? Thanks you so much though

Comment: I'm wondering why C++ standard committee doesn't introduce "break with label" and "continue with label"? It is much more concise way of doing such things if you ask me.